# How to partition a set so that the difference between the sum of two sets is their maximum

Tags: algorithm

Let S be a set of n positive integers, where n is even. Give an efficient
algorithm to partition S into two subsets S1 and S2 of n/2 elements each
with the property that the difference between the sum of the elements
in S1 and the sum of the elements in S2 is maximum. What is the time
complexity of your algorithm.
This is a question from *Algorithms*, but I cannot figure out what's the meaning of "the difference between the sum of the elements in S1 and the sum of the elements in S2 is maximum".

Comment: When you sum the elements of S1 and the elements of S2 you get two integers i1 and i2 -- here we look at the difference between the two numbers (i2 - i1). Obiously, this difference depends on the values i1 and i2 which in turn depend on how you split up the original set into your two subsets S1 and S2. The question here is: how can you split up the original set so that the value (i2 - i1) is as big as possible?

Comment: Thank you! I think this is where i'm stuck. I thought the two sets' "maximum" is different, but actually it means make their difference maximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
S = RadixSort(S) // O(N)
S1 = S[0..(N/2)-1]
S2 = S[N/2..N-1]
```

Abs(Sum(lowest values) - Sum(highest values)) will be the maximum difference.